# curl_init($url) returns Resource id #7

Tags: php

There is a CURL functionality that i'd been using to fetch image from a url and save it to m server, since COPY() was disabled from my hosting .

the url i passed was $url=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/People_from_Switzerland.png/285px-People_from_Switzerland.png

```
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';   
$userAgent = 'php';
$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

And I get the following error when i tried to echo the curl_init($url) output

process Resource id #7
**Warning**:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in 
**Warning**:  curl_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Please Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Where does the `$ch` come from, you use `$process` before, is the last line copied from other place?

The undefined variable will be null.

Comment: Thanks for answering ..you are right..I had used CURL at two different functions for different purpose and while pasting I had forgotten to replace this one variable...

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to change `$ch` to `$process` in your last line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

should be:

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP This downloads the image file from any url you give and save it. I used it for facebook.

```
$headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';  
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';

$userAgent = 'php';
$process = curl_init('https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/xxxx/xxxxxx_n.jpg');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);     
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$raw=curl_exec($process);
curl_close ($process);
$open=fopen('final.jpeg',x);
$write=fwrite($open,$raw);
$clo= fclose($open);
```